# parsing json text

Tags: javascript, json

for example i have this json object:

```
{"h":["username","hair_color","height"],"d":[["ali","brown",1.2],["mar 
c","blue",1.4],["joe","brown",1.7],["zehua","black",1.8]]}
```

how do i convert this into:

```
[{"username":"ali","hair_color":"brown","height":1.2},{"username":"mar 
c","hair_color":"blue","height":1.4},{"username":"joe","hair_color":"b 
rown","height":1.7},{"username":"zehua","hair_color":"black","height": 
1.8}]
```

using javascript

Comment: There's nothing about JSON in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = {"h":["username","hair_color","height"],"d":[["ali","brown",1.2],["mar c","blue",1.4],["joe","brown",1.7],["zehua","black",1.8]]}
b = []
for(var i = 0; i < a.d.length; i++){
   b.push({});
   for (var j = 0; j < a.h.length; j++) {
     b[b.length-1][a.h[j]] = a.d[i][j];
   }
}
alert(b[2].username) //joe
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no "special" way to do it. Assuming the first example is a JSON string, you need to first run it through `JSON.parse`, and then iterate over the resulting object to generate the structure you want.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jani said, parsing the JSON is the easy part. You need to do some transformations, here it is with a little help from jQuery:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"h":["username","hair_color","height"],"d":[["ali","brown",1.2],["marc","blue",1.4],["joe","brown",1.7],["zehua","black",1.8]]}')

// the array of keys (username, hair, height)
var keys = obj.h
// the array of values (arrays)
var values = obj.d

// map the values array to a new one
var users = $.map(values, function(userdata, i){
  var user = {}
  // assign this user's values for each key
  $.each(keys, function(key_index, key){
    user[key] = userdata[key_index]
  })
  return user
})
```

Comment: I wont be using jquery. But anyway this answer is still helpful.  thanks